# IE9 adjacent image overlaps/appears in the pop-up image

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS hover to create a pop-up image when a smaller image is moused over. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome but in IE9 the adjacent(side) image appears to overlap with the pop-up image.

Thank you!

CSS:

```
.thumbnail{
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 0;
    float: left; 
    clear: both;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.thumbnail:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 50;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.thumbnail span{ 
    position: absolute; 
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0px; 
    left: -1000px; 
    border: 1px ridge gray;
    visibility: hidden; 
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
}
.bdecor{
    background-color:#CD2626;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 1px;    
}

/*CSS for enlarged image*/
.thumbnail span img{ 
    border-width: 0; 
    padding: 0px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.thumbnail:hover span{
    visibility: visible; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a z-index higher than the original image to your enlarged image hover. Please use code below:

```
.thumbnail:hover span{
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Having seen this http://jsfiddle.net/Abhatt/UUJNs/8/ in the comments, I would add:

Ignoring the CSS for the moment you have some bad html. You have put an `<a>` inside another `<a>` and you didn't close off the second one either. But not closing it off is inconsequential as it is invalid to put an `<a>` within an `<a>`. So you need to change that. Also you cannot have an `<input>` within an `<a>` tag either.

Once you change those hopefully the issue will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the response and my apologies for not responding sooner. I added the code above but to no avail - the adjacent image still overlaps the pop-up image.

Comment: @ams Could you post your html as well then please and/or set up a http://jsfiddle.net so that I can better help you?

Comment: Sure, I will do so and let you know asap! Thanks!

Comment: I uploaded the html and css here - http://jsfiddle.net/Abhatt/UUJNs/8/ - please note that the content is being pulled using php from a mySQL database so I had to remove that content. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you for calling out the shoddy html (to my defense; I didn't write it but I should have fixed it). The overlap has vanished in IE9! Yay!

Comment: @ams Happy to have helped. Could you please check the tick next to the answer to accept it.